# Map text field to nested object

Tags: glass-mapper

I have a model which has two nested classes within. I am unable to find any resources how to map this correctly.

In Sitecore the Address.cs corresponds to the template Address which has a droplink to a Market. The market contains several fields which should me mapped to Market.cs as well as a single-text field which should be mapped to Text.cs.

```
public class Address{

    [SitecoreField(FieldName = Templates.AddressItem.Fields.Market_FieldName)]
    public virtual Market Market {get; set;}
    .... other properties
}
```

With the Market.cs model:

```
public class Market{
    [SitecoreField(FieldName = Templates.MarketItem.Fields.MarketName_FieldName)]
    public virtual Text Name {get; set}
    ... other properties
}
```

And Text.cs

```
public class Text{
    public virtual string Text {get; set;}
    public virtual bool IsStandardValue {get; set;}
    ... other properties
}
```

Obviously, directly mapping it using `[SitecoreField(FieldName = Templates.AddressItem.Fields.Market_FieldName)]` does not work.

How would I map the `Market` object, and the `Text` object properly as well as the `IsStandardValue`? (Can be gotten from `Item.Field.ContainsStandardValue`.)

Comment: What is the name, in Sitecore, of the fields "Market" and "Name"?

Comment: "Market" and "MarketName"

Comment: Did you try [SitecoreField("Market")] and [SitecoreField("MarketName")] and using virtual for both? In the first case you don't even need SitecoreField - I only use it if the name of the field differs from that of the Sitecore one (or if the Sitecore one has spaces in it).

Comment: Sorry it should already have been virtual. The Templates.MarketItem.Fields.MarketItem_FieldName cotains the strings you mentoined. But this throws a GlassMapper.Mapper.MapperException since it does not know how to map a droplink field into a Market object, which propagates to it not knowing how to map a text field to a Text object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the attribute `[SitecoreSelf]` to continue mapping the current item on a nested object:

```
public class Market
{
    [SitecoreSelf]
    public virtual Text Name { get; set }
}
```

Then on the `Text` class you add the `[SitecoreField]` attribute to get the text field mapped.

```
public class Text
{
    [SitecoreField(FieldName = Templates.MarketItem.Fields.MarketName_FieldName)]
    public virtual string Text {get; set;}

    // Use custom mapper
    [DataMapper(typeof(ContainsStandardValueMapper))]
    [SitecoreField(FieldName = Templates.MarketItem.Fields.MarketName_FieldName)]
    public virtual bool IsStandardValue {get; set;}
}
```

For for the `IsStandardValue` property you need to create a custom mapper.

```
public class ContainsStandardValueMapper : AbstractDataMapper
{
    public override void MapToCms(AbstractDataMappingContext mappingContext)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object MapToProperty(AbstractDataMappingContext mappingContext)
    {
        var scConfig = Configuration as SitecoreFieldConfiguration;
        var scContext = mappingContext as SitecoreDataMappingContext;

        var field = Glass.Mapper.Sc.Utilities.GetField(scContext.Item, scConfig.FieldId, scConfig.FieldName);

        if (field == null)
            return false;

        return field.ContainsStandardValue;
    }

    public override bool CanHandle(AbstractPropertyConfiguration configuration, Context context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

If you often use the `Text` class pattern then maybe it would make sense to create a custom mapper for that type instead.

Comment: Hi Soren, it partially solved my problem so I accepted it. However, my Configuration is null so I can't get the field. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all of your models have the `[SitecoreType]` attribute on them, too:

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{ADDRESS-TEMPLATE-ID}")]
public class Address {
    [SitecoreField(FieldName = Templates.AddressItem.Fields.Market_FieldName)]
    public virtual Market Market {get; set;}
    .... other properties
}

[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{MARKET-TEMPLATE-ID}")]
public class Market {
    [SitecoreField(FieldName = Templates.MarketItem.Fields.MarketName_FieldName)]
    public virtual string Name {get; set}
    ... other properties
}
```

Comment: Hi, the Text object is not a Sitecore item but a single-line text field, so that field needs to be mapped to the Text object, how would I do that?

Comment: In that case, you can just use `string` for the type for that field. I'm not sure how to populate a property like `IsStandardValue`, but that's probably a separate question, so I would recommend asking a new one with that specific question.